# How to make text area text automatically go to the next line when line is finished?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

This is my code for text field. It is not changing the line when the line ends, but    continues to go on, making the frame look weird.

I tried to use a scroll pane, but it did not help me.

```
JTextArea TextArea = new JTextArea(7,10);
gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
TextPanel.add(TextArea, gridConstraints);
TextArea.setEditable(true);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Without line & word wrapping, the size of a `JTextArea` will grow beyond its original size. You could call:

```
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

---

Side notes:

- `JTextArea` are typically placed in `JScollPane` containers to facilitate scrolling.
- Java naming conventions indicate that variables start with a *lowercase* letter, making `TextArea` `textArea`

Comment: +1 Add it word wrap as well (as a side note) and you have yourself an excellent answer

Comment: No problem, see this [great post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021860/jtextarea-word-wrap-resizing?answertab=oldest#tab-top) from @MadProgrammer :))

Comment: What happens when madness meets crazy on SO?

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a solution if you are using SceneBuilder.

Select the TextArea-element from the hierarchy-tree, go to "Inspector", select the tab "Properties" and activate "Wrap Text".

Then, every text within the TextArrea-element will have a return at the end of the line.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLe4v.jpg)

Cheers